# method redefined warning while running Merb 0.9.3

Tags: ruby, merb

I get numerous "method redefined" warnings while running an application under Merb 0.9.3. Of course, I get this only when I run my script using the ruby -w option. Is there any way to get rid of the methods getting redefined (repeated loading of files) again and again?

Has this been resolved in Merb 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about your issue but Merb 1.0 works great for me. I also recommend using the latest version, there are a some bugs fixed even from 1.0.x.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you get warnings may depend on which ruby version or warning level you use, as can be seen in [this gist](http://gist.github.com/217992).

Or maybe they fixed stuff between 0.93 and 1.0 .